# Python | using List , Nested For loop with *different* variable same list

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop, nested

For a given 'list' , I have used a nested "For" Loop with a different variable . I am not sure why I am getting first item of the first "For" loop repeated once . According to my understanding , it should not repeated . It would be great if some one can make me understand why this is happening only when I use different variable whereas when I use the same variable , it works as expected.
Please refer the snapshot.
Please note : I am very new to coding and this is my first programming language.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdWZA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH3YD.png)

Comment: To help see what is going on, I would recommend changing your print(c) and print(j) statements to print(f'c={c}') and print(ff'j={j}).

(There is something funky with your first example, but I think that may have to do with whether your Console is getting cleared between executions. The two examples should give the same output.  Just in the second the reuse of c means you have overwritten the outer loop variable and so can't use it's value in the inner loop.)

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Variable Shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

You can read more about it here:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-shadowing-in-python
- https://oznetnerd.com/2017/07/17/python-shadowing/